# Determine with pandas if values in two columns are close to each other

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
    max  hits
0   NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2   NaN  True (bad)
3   NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN
6   True NaN
7   NaN  True (good)
8   NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN
10  NaN  True (good)
11  True NaN
12  NaN  NaN
13  NaN  NaN
```

I want to count how many True values in 'hits' column are near with True values in 'max' column. Proximity criterion is two steps up and two steps down. So in my example answer is 2.

Now I count this way:

```
# get indexes of True values in hits column
indexes = df.dropna(subset = ['hits']).index
count = 0
for index in indexes:
    df_slice = df_work.iloc [index-2 : index+2+1].dropna(subset = ['max'])
    if len(df_slice) > 0:
        count += 1 # True in 'hits' is close to True value in 'max'
```

It works as expected, but very slowly. My DataFrame is very large and I loose many time. Is there a faster way?

Updated:
It started to fly using this method:

```
df.hits.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True, limit=2)
df.hits.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True, limit=2)
count = len (df.dropna(subset=['hits', 'max'], inplace=False, how = 'any'))
```

Comment: What happens if there is a `True` at row `8` of `max`?

Comment: @QuangHoang accepted. count += 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `bfill/ffill` with `limit`:

```
(df.hits.bfill(limit=2).ffill(limit=2) & df['max']).sum()
# out 2
```

Comment: Dear friend, it works but slower than my original version. Please view updated topic.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by original version. On my computer, my version takes 1.8ms, while your `for index in indexes` loop takes 3.2 ms.

Comment: it started to fly now. I updated the post. This is not the solution you suggested, but I came up with it thanks to your help. Just reworked it a bit. Thanks, dear friend!

Answer (score 1):

#Introduce a test column

```
df=df.assign(test=df.sum(1).replace(0, np.nan).fillna(method='ffill',limit=2))

#Create Condition and Choices
cond=[df.hits.notna()&df['test'].ne(df['test'].shift(3)),df.hits.notna()&df['test'].eq(df['test'].shift(3))]
choices=['bad','good']

#Update staus using np.where
df['status']=np.select(cond,choices,'')
print(df)

    max  hits  test status
0    NaN   NaN   NaN       
1    NaN   NaN   NaN       
2    NaN  True   1.0    bad
3    NaN   NaN   1.0       
4    NaN   NaN   1.0       
5    NaN   NaN   NaN       
6   True   NaN   1.0       
7    NaN  True   1.0   good
8    NaN   NaN   1.0       
9    NaN   NaN   1.0       
10   NaN  True   1.0   good
11  True   NaN   1.0       
12   NaN   NaN   1.0       
13   NaN   NaN   1.0
```